# Only looping through even numbers

Tags: python

I am new to programming so forgive me if this is basic.

Below is part of my code for extracting Home and Away odds from many different bookmakers for a basketball match.
If I just loop through every element in the range, I am left with home and away odds all in one column, however, I want a separate column for home and away odds.

```
num_page_items = len(odds)
for i in range(num_page_items):
    Home = (odds[2*i].text)
    Away = (odds[2*i-1].text)
print(Home,Away)
```

My desired outcome is to display the home team odds next to the away team odds separated by a comma.
My code achieves this, however I believe it is not a great way of doing it as it technically runs into an error at the end (even though all of the data I'm after still displays).

How can I clean this up?
Thanks

Comment: What is `odds` value?

Comment: You're running into an error because you're counting for too long. So, what to do? Don't count to the end. Only count to the half.

Comment: Reformat the code as it would have `IndentationError`.

Comment: What at least is `type(odds)`?

Answer (score 2):

You can create an iterable with a generator expression to extract the text attribute from the `odd` objects, and then pair them by zipping the iterable with itself, so that you can iterate through it to unpack `Home` and `Away`:

```
i = (odd.text for odd in odds)
for Home, Away in zip(i, i):
    print(Home, Away)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num_page_items = len(odds)
for i in range(0, num_page_items, 2):
    Home = odds[i].text  # Starts from 0, goes till num_page_items, incrementing by 2 (even indices)
for i in range(1, num_page_items, 2):
    Away = odds[i].text # Starts from 1, goes till num_page_items, incrementing by 2 (odd indices)
```

You run into an IndexError, since you access an element at index 2*i, where i iterates over values from 0 to the size of the list. For eg, if size is 10, you will end up trying to access odds[2*i] for i = 5, 6, 7... , the index of which is out of bounds

Answer (score 0):

Another way to go is to do a check inside the `for-loop` whether `i` is odd or even. Just a work around of Shobhit Verma's answer.

```
num_page_items = len(odds)
for i in range(num_page_items):
    if i % 2 == 0:                    #This is a sanity check to see if i is odd or even
        Home = odds[i].text
    else:
        Away = odds[i].text
```

Answer (score 0):

The `itemgetter` in the standard module `operator` is designed to select list contents. Fast, suitable for regular selection.

```py
from operator import itemgetter
odds=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
num_page_items = len(odds)

getHome = itemgetter(*range(0,num_page_items,2))
getAway = itemgetter(*range(1,num_page_items,2))
Home = getHome(odds)
Away = getAway(odds)
print(Home)
print(Away)
```

Output:

```
(1, 3, 5)
(2, 4, 6)
```